# Make field visible depended on other field - Powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I have a radio button . If my radio button is Yes then it should show me text box

Answer (score 0):

To set the visibility of a control, you can look at the `Visible` property. If the name of your radio button control is `Radio1`, for example, then you can set the Visible property of the text box to

```
Radio1.Selected.Value = "Yes"
```